# Power BI Direct query mode - handle multiple tables

Tags: sql, powerbi, azure-sql-database

I have a azure sql db where all tables sit - fact, dimension other lookups. Have a requirement to pull(3 tables) a fact table, a dimension and another lookup table(not part of star schema) via direct query and be part of data model within Power BI.
Direct query doesn't allow more than one table to query against(from a single source).
Any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: Can you expand on this: Direct query doesn't allow more than one table to query against(from a single source). As direct query can handle many tables etc from a single source

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.. thanks to Jon's response, it triggered me to look further and I have found that for each table(from same source) I have to go through 'get data' process.
Initially, I thought via one 'get data' process I could multi select tables, but, obviously not.
All ok here now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with mysql db, I able to select multiple tables and load once to power bi.

***New Source -> Database -> Mysql Database -> Add host and password ----> then you retrieve window with table list --> it views tables, views , procedures etc....***

Comment: thanks, that works ok too. But, what i was trying to do was in advance query window, write select * from table1 select * from table2 and it only took output from

Comment: first select query.

Comment: It may cause for performance for power bi, you can simply create sql view for that